# OFFSETOF macro structure field

Tags: c, macros, struct

the code to update field of structure using OFFSETOF macro

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#define OFFSETOF(TYPE, ELEMENT) ((size_t)&(((TYPE *)0)->ELEMENT))   

typedef struct PodTag {    
int     i;    
double  d;    
char    c; 
}PodType;   

#pragma pack(1)
int main() 
{    
     char arr[20] = {'\0'};
     arr[0] = 0x1;
     PodType instance;
     printf("%d\n", OFFSETOF(PodType, c));   
     memset(&instance,0,sizeof(PodType)); 
     memcpy(&instance+OFFSETOF(PodType, c),&arr[0],sizeof(char));
     printf("Val of C = %d\n",instance.c); // value is not reflected
     getchar();    
return 0; 
}
```

Here i am doing memcpy . the value does not reflect. whats wrong

```
memcpy(&instance+OFFSETOF(PodType, c),&arr[0],sizeof(unsigned char));
```

Can we do something like this to update the structure field

```
#define OFFSETOF_DATA(TYPE, ELEMENT,data) \
  (*((size_t)&(((TYPE *)0)->ELEMENT)) = (unsigned char)(data))
```

Comment: Why did you write your own `OFFSETOF` macro when a standard version of `offseof` it is available from standard library's header `stddef.h`?

Comment: Why do you use an `offsetof` macro when you just could do `&instance.c`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is causing trouble:

```
 memcpy(&instance+OFFSETOF(PodType, c),&arr[0],sizeof(char));
```

It is treating `&instance` as the start of an array, and adding a number such as 16 to it, thereby accessing the `i` element of the sixteenth member of the fictitious array.

You need to use:

```
 memcpy((char *)&instance+OFFSETOF(PodType, c), &arr[0], sizeof(char));
```

This adds the correct number of bytes to the byte address of `&instance`.  Note that the `char *` cast is independent of the fact that `c` is a `char` field; you'd still use a `char *` cast there even if you were accessing the `i` or `d` elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define OFFSETOF(TYPE, ELEMENT) ((size_t)&(((TYPE *)0)->ELEMENT))

typedef struct PodTag
{
    int i;
    double d;
    char c;
} PodType;

int main(void)
{
    char arr[20] = {'\0'};
    arr[0] = 0x1;
    PodType instance;
    printf("%zu\n", OFFSETOF(PodType, c));
    memset(&instance, 0, sizeof(PodType));
    memcpy((char *)&instance+OFFSETOF(PodType, c), &arr[0], sizeof(char));
    printf("Val of C = %d\n", instance.c);
    return 0;
}
```

Example output (Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks; GCC 4.8.2, 64-bit compilation):

```
16
Val of C = 1
```

Comment: Correct answer but kind-of incomplete. All this `OFFSETOF` stuff is completely useless, the OP should use `&instance.c` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`(TYPE*)0`<< will be a NULL pointer.

Comment: memcpy(&instance+OFFSETOF(PodType, c),&arr[0],sizeof(char));
&instance will be some base address of struct & will return offset..should work isn;t it

Comment: I don't disagree with your statement, but I think that it being `NULL` is exactly the intention. Then, cast the NULL to the appropriate type, and take the address of the element, since its from NULL, the address will be the offset.

Comment: @Macattack: Yes, but strictly speaking, this is not portable. The physical representation of null pointer does not have to point to zero address specifically. I.e formally `(TYPE *) 0` can point to `0xABCD1234` address, which will immediately break the intended functionality of this macro. This is actually why one has to wonder why the OP decided to re-implement something that has always been readily available from standard library as `offsetof` macro defined in `stddef.h`.

Comment: And formally, this macro indeed triggers undefined behavior since it attempts to dereference a null pointer.